# Display Object details with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a project were I have an array that I am looping through. The project is working correctly I am using React Router and useParams to have my project functionality.

I am trying to have the button at the bottom of each object displayed. That would only display that object with it details and nothing else.

App.js (all components are here)

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import HeroeList from './HeroeList';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import AddHero from './AddHero';
import HeroDetail from './HeroDetail';

function App() {
  const [heroes, setHeroes] = useState([
    { heroName: 'Superman', pic: 'https://cosmicbook.news/sites/default/files/henry-cavill-justice-league-brhv.jpg', powers: 'Flight, Speed, Strength', bio: 'Superman was born on the planet Krypton and was given the name Kal-El at birth. As a baby, his parents sent him to Earth in a small spaceship moments before Krypton was destroyed in a natural cataclysm', id: 1 },
    { heroName: 'Flash', pic:'https://hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/flash-justice-league-unite-2017-on.jpg', powers: 'Super Speed, Time Travel', bio: 'Barry Allen is The Flash, the fastest man alive. Using his super-speed powers, he taps into the Speed Force and becomes a costumed crime-fighter', id: 2},
    { heroName: 'Wonder-Women', pic:'https://images.hdqwalls.com/download/justice-league-wonder-woman-2018-yy-1080x2160.jpg', powers: 'Strength, Speed, Lasso of truth', bio: 'Wonder Woman is the princess Diana, the daughter of Hippolyta, Queen of the Amazons and Zeus, the mightiest of the Gods of Olympus.', id: 3},
    { heroName: 'Batman',pic:'https://images.hdqwalls.com/download/batman-justice-league-unite-2017-qu-720x1280.jpg', powers: 'Super intelligence', bio:'Batman is the superhero protector of Gotham City, a tortured, brooding vigilante dressed as a sort of human bat who fights against evil and strikes fear into the hearts of criminals everywhere.', id: 4}
  ])
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <HeroeList heroes={heroes}/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/AddHero">
            <AddHero />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/HeroDetail/:id">
            <HeroDetail heroes={heroes}/>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

HeroeList.js (display all object along with a button under each)

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const HeroeList = ({ heroes }) => {
    
    return ( 
        <div>
        {heroes.map(heroe =>
            <div className="heroe-preview" key={heroe.id}>
              <h2>{heroe.heroName}</h2>
              <img src={heroe.pic} alt="Heroe" />
              <p>Superpowers :{heroe.powers}</p>
              <p>Biography :{heroe.bio}</p>
              <Link to={`heroes/${heroe.id}`}>
              <button>Read more</button>
              </Link>              
            </div>
            )}
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default HeroeList;
```

HeroDetail.js (this is not displaying anything)

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const HeroDetail = (props) => {
    const heroes = props.heroes; 
   

    const { id } = useParams();
    return ( 
        <div>
            <h2>{heroes.id}</h2>
            <p>{heroes.heroName}</p>
            <p>{heroes.powers}</p>
            <p>{heroes.bio}</p>
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default HeroDetail;
```

Answer (score 2):

the route path and the link are not the same:

```
<Route path="/HeroDetail/:id">
  <HeroDetail heroes={heroes}/>
</Route>
```

while the Link is

```
<Link to={`heroes/${heroe.id}`}>
  <button>Read more</button>
</Link>
```

so either you change the Route **path** to `/heroes/:id`
or
update Link **to** `/HeroDetail/${heroe.id}`

Comment: I have updated both links to /HerDetail/ but still no change

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue after using a filter and map method. This allowed me to filter the array based on the useParams passed in. Also the logical operator to use needs to be "==" and not "===".

import { useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const GetItems = ({heroes}) => {
const { id } = useParams();
return (

{heroes.filter(superHero => superHero.id == id).map(newSuperArray =>(

### {newSuperArray.heroName}

{newSuperArray.powers}

{newSuperArray.bio}

))}

);
}

export default GetItems;